# python calling a main thread function from another thread via value rather than reference

Tags: python, multithreading, websocket, nonblocking, pyqtgraph

so I've been thinking about this for a couple days now and I cant figure it out, I've searched around but couldn't find the answer I was looking for, so any help would be greatly appreciated.

Essentially what I am trying to do is call a method on a group of objects in my main thread from a separate thread, just once after 2 seconds and then the thread can exit, I'm just using threading as a way of creating a non-blocking 2 second pause (if there are other ways of accomplishing this please let me know.

So I have a pyqtplot graph/plot that updates from a websocket stream and the gui can only be updated from the thread that starts it (the main one).
What happens is I open a websocket stream fill up a buffer for about 2 seconds, make an REST request, apply the updates from the buffer to the data from the REST request and then update the data/plot as new messages come in.  Now the issue is I can't figure out how to create a non blocking 2 second pause in the main thread without creating a child thread.  If I create a child thread and pass the object that contains the dictionary I want to update after 2 seconds, I get issues regarding updating the plot from a different thread.  So what I THINK is happening is when that new spawned thread is spawned the reference to the object I want to update is actually the object itself, or the data (dictionary) containing the update data is now in a different thread as the gui and that causes issues.

open websocket --> start filling buffer --> wait 2 seconds --> REST request --> apply updates from buffer to REST data --> update data as new websocket updates/messages come in.

Unfortunately the websocket and gui only start when you run `pg.exec()` and you can't break them up to start individually, you create them and then start them together (or at least I have failed to find a way to start them individually, alternatively I also tried using a separate library to handle websockets however this requires starting a thread for incoming messages as well)

This is the minimum reproducible example, sorry it's pretty long but I couldn't really break it down anymore without removing required functionality as well as preserving context:

```
import json
import importlib
from requests.api import get
import functools
import time
import threading
import numpy as np
import pyqtgraph as pg
from pyqtgraph.Qt import QtCore
QtWebSockets = importlib.import_module(pg.Qt.QT_LIB + '.QtWebSockets')

class coin():
    def __init__(self):
        self.orderBook = {'bids':{}, 'asks':{}}
        self.SnapShotRecieved = False
        self.last_uID = 0
        self.ordBookBuff = []
        self.pltwgt = pg.PlotWidget()
        self.pltwgt.show()
        self.bidBar = pg.BarGraphItem(x=[0], height=[1], width= 1, brush=(25,25,255,125), pen=(0,0,0,0))
        self.askBar = pg.BarGraphItem(x=[1], height=[1], width= 1, brush=(255,25,25,125), pen=(0,0,0,0))
        self.pltwgt.addItem(self.bidBar)
        self.pltwgt.addItem(self.askBar)

    def updateOrderBook(self, message):
        for side in ['a','b']:
            bookSide = 'bids' if side == 'b' else 'asks'
            for update in message[side]:
                if float(update[1]) == 0:
                    try:
                        del self.orderBook[bookSide][float(update[0])]
                    except:
                        pass
                else:
                    self.orderBook[bookSide].update({float(update[0]): float(update[1])})
            while len(self.orderBook[bookSide]) > 1000:
                del self.orderBook[bookSide][(min(self.orderBook['bids'], key=self.orderBook['bids'].get)) if side == 'b' else (max(self.orderBook['asks'], key=self.orderBook['asks'].get))]
        if self.SnapShotRecieved == True:
            self.bidBar.setOpts(x0=self.orderBook['bids'].keys(), height=self.orderBook['bids'].values(), width=1 )
            self.askBar.setOpts(x0=self.orderBook['asks'].keys(), height=self.orderBook['asks'].values(), width=1 )

    def getOrderBookSnapshot(self):
        orderBookEncoded = get('https://api.binance.com/api/v3/depth?symbol=BTCUSDT&limit=1000')
        if orderBookEncoded.ok: 
            rawOrderBook = orderBookEncoded.json() 
            orderBook = {'bids':{}, 'asks':{}}
            for orders in rawOrderBook['bids']:
                orderBook['bids'].update({float(orders[0]): float(orders[1])})
            for orders in rawOrderBook['asks']:
                orderBook['asks'].update({float(orders[0]): float(orders[1])})
            last_uID = rawOrderBook['lastUpdateId']
            while self.ordBookBuff[0]['u'] <= last_uID: 
                del self.ordBookBuff[0]
                if len(self.ordBookBuff) == 0:
                    break
            if len(self.ordBookBuff) >= 1 :
                for eachUpdate in self.ordBookBuff:
                    self.last_uID = eachUpdate['u']
                    self.updateOrderBook(eachUpdate)
                self.ordBookBuff = []
            self.SnapShotRecieved = True
        else:
            print('Error retieving order book.') #RESTfull request failed


def on_text_message(message, refObj):
    messaged = json.loads(message)
    if refObj.SnapShotRecieved == False:
        refObj.ordBookBuff.append(messaged)
    else:
        refObj.updateOrderBook(messaged)

def delay(myObj):
    time.sleep(2)
    myObj.getOrderBookSnapshot()
 
def main():
    pg.mkQApp()
    refObj = coin()
    websock = QtWebSockets.QWebSocket()
    websock.connected.connect(lambda : print('connected'))
    websock.disconnected.connect(lambda : print('disconnected'))
    websock.error.connect(lambda e : print('error', e))
    websock.textMessageReceived.connect(functools.partial(on_text_message, refObj=refObj))
    url = QtCore.QUrl("wss://stream.binance.com:9443/ws/btcusdt@depth@1000ms")
    websock.open(url)
    getorderbook = threading.Thread(target = delay, args=(refObj,),  daemon=True) #, args = (lambda : websocketThreadExitFlag,)
    getorderbook.start()
    pg.exec()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: Use `def main(): ... if __name__ == '__main__': main()` and move the code in `def main`

Comment: [Why should you use if __name__ __main__](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=g_wlZ9IhbTs)

Comment: Fixed it, sorry about that, thanks for pointing that out because now it actually more closely resembles the code it was boiled down from., including passing references around which original post did not include